# Laravel 5 Delete existing Article with destroy method

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to delete an article with the following code:

ArticlesController:

```
public function destroy($id) {
  $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
  $article->delete();

  return redirect('backend/dashboard')->with([
    'flash_message' => 'Deleted',
    'flash_message_important' => false
  ]);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($articles as $key => $article)
  <tr>
    <td class="td-actions text-right">
      <a  href="{{action('ArticlesController@edit',$article->id)}}"type="button" rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs" data-original-title="Edit Article">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="{{action('ArticlesController@destroy',$article->id)}}" type="button" rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs" data-original-title="Delete Article">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforech
```

By clicking the "Delete Article" Button I am redirected to a total different view. It seems like the @show method is executed.

My Routes:

```
Route::get('backend/articles/archive', 'ArticlesController@archive');
Route::resource('backend/articles', 'ArticlesController');
Route::get('backend/dashboard', [
  'middleware' => 'auth',
  'uses' => 'PagesController@dashboard'
]);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you leave change the redirect like so `redirect()` ?

Comment: Can you add your related routes to the question?

Comment: with redirect() nothing changes. same result

Comment: @ Roj Vroemen: Question updated with routes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because you are using **a** tag.
Use the **form** tag with method equals to delete which will solve your problem.

```
          @foreach($articles as $key => $article)
            <tr>
             <td class="td-actions text-right">
                <a  href="{{action('ArticlesController@edit',$article->id)}}"type="button" rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs" data-original-title="Edit Article">
                  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                </a>

                {{ Form::open([ 'method'  => 'delete', 'route' => [ 'items.destroy', $item->id ] ]) }}
                    {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
                {{ Form::close() }}

             </td>
            </tr>
            @endforech
```

Comment: @ Sameer Shaikh: So just to get this right. What's the reason for the exception with an a tag? And why does it work with a Form? Why can't I simply call the @destroy method without a Form?

Comment: Because the http method required to delete a resource is "DELETE". Normal link has Http method of "GET" And not delete.excluding get request all other request can only be made through form. ie. Put,Patch,Delete etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try to do like this

```
public function destroy($id) {
  $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
  $article->delete();

  return view('dashboard')->with([
    'flash_message' => 'Deleted',
    'flash_message_important' => false
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `delete` method to call `destroy()` action, for example:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'Delete', 'route' => ['article.destroy', $id]]) !!}
<button type="submit" class="btn">Delete article</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

You can't use `a href` link here.

Comment: So just to get this right. What's the reason for the exception with an a tag? And why does it work with a Form? Why can't I simply call the @destroy method without a Form?

Comment: You can use destroy without form but then you need to create an ajax call which needs even more lines of code than this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the variables correctly.

```
$url = action('UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-action